# How to calculate the matrix's inverse using tflite

Tags: tensorflow, matrix-inverse, tflite

as far as i known, the matrix's inverse is a common operator.

while tf.raw_ops.MatrixInverse is not supported in tflite and BatchMatrixInverse is not available in GraphDef version 1205.

How can i calculate the inverse of the matrix in tflite?

Best wishes

Comment: Hi @jiaocha, Try using tf.linalg.inv( ) to find the inverse matrix. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Before you convert your model to tflite model you have to enable TF ops to work in tflite by using the below code

```
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,  # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
    tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS  # enable TensorFlow ops.
]
```

For more details please refer to this [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select#convert_a_model). Thank You.